# What is the function of a small extra towel folded and placed in hotel beds?

Tags: hotels

There are small extra towels placed on hotel beds despite the normal bathroom towels. What purpose do they serve?

Comment: Are you talking about the throw that goes across the foot of the bed? That is either decorative, to provide extra warmth, or to protect the duvet from your shoes, depending who you ask and what your habits are.

Comment: The canonical does not cover those placed on the bed does it?